# Listview not loading images till I scroll the screen

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am using an async call inside my Custom Adapter class to load images in a Listview. However, the images are not shown till I scroll up/down atleast slightly. Please let me know what might be the reason. Thanks for your help.

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{ 
    private String fileName = null;
    private ImageView imgViewToLoad = null;

    LoadImage(String fileName, ImageView imgViewToLoad)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.imgViewToLoad = imgViewToLoad;
    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args)
{   
    return null;
}

//This is executed on main UI thread
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Utils.mImageFetcher.loadImage(fileName, imgViewToLoad);
}
}


This is in my getView()
----------------------

ViewHolderIncomingImg holderInImg = null;
if (null != convertView && 
  (convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderIncomingImg && !isFirstMsg))
{
  holderInImg = (ViewHolderIncomingImg) convertView.getTag();
  if (!multiSelectionMode)
  {
      if (!mSelectedItemsIds.get(position) && convertView.isActivated())
          convertView.setActivated(false);
  }
}
else
{
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.conv_list_item_incoming_img, parent, false);
  holderInImg = new ViewHolderIncomingImg();

..............

new LoadImage(convRowItems.get(position).getMessage(), holderInImg.image).execute();
```

Comment: The reasen is most likely view recycling. Please post your code, everything else would be guessing.

Comment: Please show your code of Adapter.

Comment: Ensure that you call the NotifyDataSetChanged method on the Adapter after the async call has completed

Comment: I have added the relevant part of code from the adapter. ImageFetcher referred in the Async call is an image loader.

Comment: An update - when I force closed my app and then re-launched it, the images showed up fine. Could there have been some minor UI issue that caused the image loading to stop abruptly ?

Answer (score 0):

As Listview use the concept of recycling its view. The images are not showing when the async call finish.

So go for listview lazy loading approach it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please share a link to some code snippet that shows lazy loading approach ?